# SWT browser does not accept the argument string encoded cp1251

Tags: java, browser, swt, jface

I have a xml file encoded cp1251 and I want to view it in swt browser, but browser.getText() return null if I run this code.

```
//....
String fileEncoding = "UTF-8"
byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.toURI()));
String text = new String(encoded,fileEncoding);
browser.setText(text);
```

I had read that browser set string encoded Unicode, m.b. I wrong encoded string from cp1251 to utf-8, or has another way to see my file in browser

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change the UTF-8 encoding to cp1251 ?

Because java internally use own encoding UTF-16,  you need to tell in which encoding you read your file, and you read it as UTF-8, but i think you need to read it as cp1251, bacause you said that your xml is encoded in cp1251, so you should read it like this:

```
String fileEncoding = "cp1251"
byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.toURI()));
String text = new String(encoded,fileEncoding);
browser.setText(text);
```

Comment: I tried it, but swt.browser.getText() all the same return null

Comment: Maybe it don't accept raw XML file, maybe you need to wrap it in <html> tag?

Comment: No, if xml have encoding UTF-8, it'll good opened in swt.browser

Comment: Java internally use own encoding UTF-16, and when you read your file as UTF-8 or cp1251 it will convert it to UTF-16 anyway. Only explanation is that the encoding of xml file is not cp1251. try with "ISO-8859-1"

Comment: Under this option, do not read Russian characters, and browser again return null((